# heroku push rejected due to gdal library

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, postgis

I wanted to deploy my application in heroku. The platform I am using are`django 1.11, django-rest-framework, postgresql, gis`. When I do `git push heroku master`, I get the following error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL
>   library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0", "gdal1.11.0",
>   "gdal1.10.0", "gdal1.9.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting
>   GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

It says to install GDAL and provide GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH. How do i provide the path for it?

I have also configured for postgresql

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

Comment: did you add `gdal` in your `requirements.txt` file

Comment: Is it available in pip?

Comment: It should be. I guess this is what you want: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/2.2.1

Comment: @Tushortz There is no pip installation shown and also I get an error doing that. If I can't install it using pip, how can i show it in requirements.txt? Also the problem is only when deploying to heroku not in the local server.

Comment: @connyctTus did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to piece together info from several places.

First, from the official Heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis#geodjango-setup Add these lines to your settings:

```
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Also add `django.contrib.gis` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Run `heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1 -a name_of_your_app` for your app.

Finally, but importantly, run `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/TrailStash/heroku-geo-buildpack -a name_of_your_app`

This worked for me with the heroku-16 stack.